# Check if user is logged in when using wordpress together with slim framework?

Tags: php, wordpress, slim

i have installed slim under my wordpress root under 
`wordpressroot/japi/`

all calls that go there are dealt with by [slim framework v3](http://slimframework.com). So are not visible to wordpress

Now I want to provide some admin functions where I have to get the current user id e.g. with: `get_current_user_id()` but i get returned 0 all the time. Is there a fix to this? do i have to call some sort of wordpress init function to be able to access these functions?

Comment: Hey, did you figure this out?

Comment: @Twigs what is your issue?

Comment: because the answer I provided seems to have solved my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i accessed the login page using https, then tried to access my slimframework over http? i think that was the mistake.

btw import you `wp-load.php` in your slim index to get access to the functions

Answer (score 0):

You can require the wordpress framework if you put this where you init the slim framework.

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( path-to-wp-root . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

This way it will load the wordpress framework, without initing the templates. Then you can use any wordpress function you need.

Comment: i actually have access to the functions... i dont think that was the problem

Comment: Didi you add this to you slim startup?